# Flash player 11.4 hungs firefox immediatly after start

Tags: firefox, flash

I have installed Flash player 11.4.402.287 on a "fresh" PC, moments after installing Windows, drivers, directX etc. After installing Flash Player Firefox totally hungs immediatly after run.

First page (adobe page, because it was launched before closing firefox) doen't load. I see new tab but FF goes hung to zero-responsivity, even loading icon stops in single position.

KMPlayer, wich uses firefox also hungs.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you provide any more details to assist with troubleshooting the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As now, only downgrade to 11.3 helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try [disabling protected mode of Flash Player](http://techdows.com/2012/06/disable-flash-players-protected-mode-for-firefox.html) and restart the computer. If that does not fix the issue, then re-enable protected mode and try something else.

Comment: it doesn't helped

Comment: That has helped me in Win8. Thanks.